# Conditional Show/Hide Field in NewForm.aspx with Javascript/Ajax

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, list-form

I want to show/hide a Field according to the selected value of a Choice field. How can i achieve this with javascript or AJAX?

Edit:

I tried this but, i cant even get the value of the selected value for the lookup dropdown:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       $('select[id$="ctl00_m_g_4baff930_989d_4f64_8728_9fb22af0d590_ctl00_ctl05_ctl09_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup"]').live("change", function()
        {
            alert($(this).val());
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

           $('select[id$="dd1"]').live("change", function()
            {

                if($(this).val()=='Completed')
                    {   
                            var title=$("[id$='textbox1']");    
                            title.show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       var title=$("[id$='textbox1']");
                       title.hide();
                    }

           });
       });
```

**new answer**

```
$('#selectField').change(function(){
if($('#selectField').val() == 'N'){
    $('#secondaryInput').hide();
} else {
    $('#secondaryInput').show();
```

}
});

I assume choice field is ur dropdonw. dd1 will be ur choice field id and textbox1 will be ur another filed id. This is just a sample but u can accomplish ur requirement like this. Dont forget to include jquery before this. I suggest u to use infopath form instead of sharepoint list forms.

Regards,

Dhaval

Comment: And how to find the ID s of the fields? From browser's View Source?

Comment: BTW,additionally i must check the selected value of the dropdown. Then show or hide the Text Field according to the selected value.

Comment: yes..only the way u can find..Sharepoint automatically generate control id like 'ctl00_m_g_49979d6a_ba67_4c70_82b0_59e0fa0787d1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField' thats why i have used $("[id$='textbox1']"). For this id u can use like $("[id$='TextField']"). And if there are multiple textbox in a form then you have to match title attribute of control too.

Comment: can you show me an example of: "And if there are multiple textbox in a form then you have to match title attribute of control too."

Comment: for that u have check for all controls inside the form with 'TextField' and then get title attribute like $("[id$='TextField']").val( $(this).attr('title') );. And for checking selected value of dropdown pls see into my updated anwser.

Comment: i tried the above code (please look at my first post) it didn't work.

Comment: have u added jquery above this?

Comment: yes i have added jquery reference

Comment: if you use full control id  then see my updated answer.

Comment: I have checked my code with infopath forms of list. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

First Provide the ID for the Row contains your Field.

Add the Following Script:

```
function hidefield()
{
   if (document.getElementById("checkboxid").checked)
   {
      document.getElementById("rowid").style.visibility = "collapse";
   }
}
```

Call this function in onclick event of the Checkbox.